# Is it possible to trigger ADF pipeline from Power App?

Tags: triggers, azure-data-factory, azure-logic-apps, powerapps

I'm wondering if it is possible to trigger an Azure Data Factory pipeline from a Microsoft Power App, and if so, how would one go about configuring this?

- I was unable to find a PowerApp connector trigger in Azure Data Factory
- I was unable to find a PowerApp connector trigger in Azure Logic Apps
- I have experience with Azure, but no experience in PowerApps

If you have any ideas or information for me that would be great.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can trigger an Azure Data Factory pipeline using the REST API like this:

> The following sample command shows you how to run your pipeline by using the REST API manually:
>
> ```
> POST  
> https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/mySubId/resourceGroups/myResourceGroup/providers/Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/myDataFactory/pipelines/copyPipeline/createRun?api-version=2017-03-01-preview
> ```

More information: [Pipeline execution and triggers in Azure Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-pipeline-execution-triggers#manual-execution-on-demand) → [Manual execution (on-demand)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-pipeline-execution-triggers#manual-execution-on-demand) → [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-pipeline-execution-triggers#rest-api)

Answer (score 0):

There is now a PowerApps connecter you can use to create a pipeline run: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/azuredatafactory/#create-a-pipeline-run